# Код на получение программ из автозапуска

Tags: delphi, windows, delphi-7

Как получить список программ из автозапуска? И во что его получать?

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s:TStrings;
  r:TRegistry;
begin
  s:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    r:=TRegistry.Create;
    try
      r.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      r.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',false);
      r.GetValueNames(s);
      Showmessage(s.Text);
      r.CloseKey;
    finally
      r.Free;
    end;
  finally
    s.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с реестром есть класс: TRegIniFiles, а там методы, с помощью которых просто вытащить необходимы вам данные.

Answer (score 0):

Автозапуск в 2 местах, реест и папка автозапуск.
Получать можешь в список ,например в **TstringList**